# Figuring out variables' class in a regression model without accessing the original data frame

Tags: r, regression, glm

I have a `rda` file that has a logistic regression model in it. Keeping other things aside if I only want to know what are the data types for the independent variables used in the `glm` how can I check those? For example if my `Y~ X1+X2+X3` how do I know what data types the `X1`, `X2` and `X3` are? At this point I do not have the data frame to investigate the data types. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by not having access to the dataframe, but the typical way to figure out the data type of an object is to use the `class()`. For example `var <- "foobar"; class(var)` returns `[1] "character"`. You are probably going to need to load the Rdata file in R, then you might be able to check the contents of the glm object with `str()`, and then try something like `class(glm$X1)`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, I'd recommend not depending on `$model`, as that will return `NULL` if `model = FALSE` was used in the function call.  `model.frame` (see my answer below) will still work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to first offer something more useful. How about checking `$terms`? (Using `fit` below as an example)

```
## or `attr(terms(fit), "dataClasses")`
attr(fit$terms, "dataClasses")
#         mpg         qsec   factor(am)           wt factor(gear) 
#   "numeric"    "numeric"     "factor"    "numeric"     "factor"
```

Since your question only mentions identifying data classes, this is sufficient. But if you want to access data for variables, check `$data`. **This is how `glm` differs from `lm`**. `glm` returns much more stuff than `lm`, including the `data` argument. Note, `lm` does not return `data`.

---

**A little more on `model.frame`**

Almost always, `model.frame` is the best procedure. But use it with some care.

```
dat <- mtcars
fit <- glm(mpg ~ qsec + factor(am) + wt + factor(gear),
           data = dat,  model = FALSE)
rm(dat)
model.frame(fit)
```

> Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'dat' not found

This is what I explained in a comment under OP's question: If `$model` is not `NULL`, `model.frame` simply extracts it. But if it is really `NULL`, `model.frame` aims to reconstruct it. But to reconstruct it, you need access to original data frame. If original data frame is not available, you get nothing (but an error).

To understand this, be aware that `model.frame` is an (S3) generic function:

```
.S3methods("model.frame")
#[1] model.frame.aovlist* model.frame.default  model.frame.glm*    
#[4] model.frame.lm*
```

`model.frame.lm` and `model.frame.glm` simple extract `$model` from model object (if `$model` is present); otherwise it calls `model.frame.default` for constructing model frame from model formula and original data frame.

Comment: Well reasoned.  It seems I've never run into the specific scenario, and hadn't thought through the consequences.  I would still argue for `model.frame` simply because it will still succeed in cases where `model = FALSE` and you have access to the data frame; `$model` will return `NULL`. It won't make a difference in the context of this question, but in other contexts it may.

Comment: attr(fit$terms, "dataClasses") solved my immediate problem. I appreciate the extra explanations. It helped me clear few more things.